# How to make a modal dialog without changing the css of backgound?

Tags: jquery, css

I have to make a modal dialog in one page, However,When I use the following lines to create a modal dialog

```
$("#mydiv").load("./d3present.html").dialog({height:900,width:700,modal:false,draggable: false});
```

The new dialog has changed my background's css and I don't know How to handle it. Moreover,the height and the width that I set do not work as well.They are like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 839px;"
```

And there is another problem:When I load 'd3present.html' page,it loads several javascripts but my original js has gone.So ,When I close the dialog,the operations on my original page did not behave as before,for less of js files.

Since I am new to jquery and any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This shold work fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function montral(){
jQuery('<div/>',{
'id'        : 'blanket',
'css'       : {
    'position'          : 'fixed',
    'background-color'  : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    'width'             : '100%',
    'height'            : '100%',
    'top'               : '0',
    'bottom'            : '0',
    'left'              : '0',
    'right'             : '0',
    'z-index'           : '100',
}
}).appendTo('body')


jQuery('<div>',{
id      : 'montral_txt',
'css'   :{
    'z-index'           : '1001',
    'position'          : 'fixed',
    'background-color'  : '#fff',
    'width'             : '400px',
    'left'              : '50%',
    'margin-left'       : '-200px',
    'top'               : '0',
    'bottom'            : '0',
    'margin-top'        : 'auto',
    'margin-bottom'     : 'auto',
    'max-height'        : '500px',
    'overflow-y'        : 'scroll',
    'overflow-x'        : 'hidden',
}
}).appendTo('#blanket');
}



</script>

<body onload="montral()">


</body>
```

Comment: @user2953208 and i use just jquery for this, no ui needed.

Comment: @ Catalin Sterian But How to close the '#montral_txt' dialog ?

Comment: @user2953208 i suggest: jQuery('#blanket').remove(); [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) you can also use jQuery('#blanket').css('display', 'none'); , but this is not recommended sice every time you acces montral() function it will create a new window and append it to body. so use .remove()  function close_montral(){ jQuery('#blanket').remove(); }

Answer (score 0):

When you download **jquery ui** you can select design theme, check it in this link [Select Theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?zThemeParams=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)
click on gallery to see all of themes but if you want a custom color else and font, background and etc you should change css by yourself

For Height and width please check outer div it is correct

Comment: I didn't set any css in my outer div

Comment: I didn't set any css in my outer div

Comment: OK I know, I mean that if you want to estimate the width and height, you have to check the outer div